# Rails select and concatenate subset of columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following ActiveRecord row:

`#<Location id: 1, name: "TEST center", description: nil, address: "Some road along the way", city: "Porto", country: "PT", latitude: nil, longitude: nil, created_at: "2015-06-05 19:03:04", updated_at: "2015-06-05 19:03:04">`

What I need to end up with is this:

`Some road along the way,Porto,PT`

Which is a coma seperated list of `address`, `city` and `country`.

I tried to call `select` and turn it into a hash first, but to no avail, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several solutions with many variations to this. Here are two:

1. You could put them in an array and then join it:

```ruby
[location.address, location.city, location.country].join(',')
```

2. You could also use string interpolation:

```ruby
"#{location.address},#{location.city},#{location.country}"
```

---

You can wrap them in a method in the model or create a Rails helper.

In the model:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base

  # Your other code here

  def description
    [address, city, country].join(',')
  end
end
```

Helper method:

```
def location_description(location)
  [location.address, location.city, location.country].join(',')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create method in `Location` model

```
def full_address
  address+", "+city+","+country
end

@location = Location.find(id)
@location.full_address
```